# Adding a menu in Android using appcelerator

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have an issue here. A new window is defined in a separate js file. And I want to add a menu to this window. So I used the following code:

```
var menu = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenu();

var item1 = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenuItem({
     title : 'Item 1',
     icon : '/images/item1.png'
});

var item2 = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenuItem({
     title : 'Refresh',
     icon : '/images/refresh.png'
});
menu.add(item1);
Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.setMenu(menu);
```

In doing so, the application has crashed. Could anyone help me figure this out?

thanks in advance!

NOTE: Developing Android application using Appcelerator.

Comment: [here is solution for this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/128856/android-menu-not-working-no-matter-what-i-do-where-am-i-going-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

always remember Set the menu on the current heavyweight window. 
To create a heavyweight window, specify one or more of

1. fullscreen,
2. navBarHidden,
3. modal

otherwise you can use you app.js file this is working.... with specify this property.

```
var menu = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenu();
var item1 = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenuItem({
    title : 'Item 1',
    icon : '/images/item1.png'
});

item1.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({ title : 'You clicked Item 1'}).show();
});
var item2 = Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.createMenuItem({
    title : 'Refresh',
    icon : '/images/refresh.png'
});
item2.addEventListener('click', function(){
    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({ title : 'You clicked Refresh'}).show();
});
menu.add(item1);
menu.add(item2);

// Set the menu on the current heavyweight window. A heavyweight window maps to an Android
// Activity. To create a heavyweight window, specify one or more of [**fullscreen**,**navBarHidden**,**modal**] to createWindow.

Titanium.UI.Android.OptionMenu.setMenu(menu);
```